# Is it a valid SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite, exception, syntax

For some reason I'm having an unhandled exception, is it the right syntax?

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username, UserEmail, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@Username, @UserEmail, @FirstName, @LastName)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", user.Email);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",  user.UserName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.FName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName",  user.LName);
```

Comment: Are you using some high-level language to build the query?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Using C#, perhaps I should put the whole code in.

Comment: I'm temped to answer this with Tcl and say: nope, everything you do is wrong, in Tcl, you have to do things differently.

Comment: @juergend Unhandled exception error, when I put it in a try{} and catch(Exception ex){} it just doesn't show any error for some reason.

Comment: Could you add more code and indicate what line is throwing the error?

Comment: Yes, you have to output the error in your `catch` block, like `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)`

Comment: The syntax is 100% correct, so it must be something else with either the `command` object itself, or the `user` object.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the following is the right query : `command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [tblUsers] ([UserEmail], [Username], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (@UserEmail ,@Username, @FirstName, @LastName)"`

Comment: That query should work too.

Comment: Fixed it ! The error was in the database, thanks a bunch !